# Underclock the microprocessor

Tags: clock, microprocessor, clock-speed

Suppose datasheet rated clock frequency range is 8MHz to 16MHz. What if we try to operate it at 6MHz. How will it impact the operation?

Comment: Do you have a specific microprocessor in mind or is this a general question?

Comment: It depends on the MCU and what does the rated clock frequency means. We can't know without a specific data sheet or MCU. Provide an example MCU.

Comment: It is a general question. Rated clock frequency means the operating frequency range defined in the datasheet.

Comment: "It is a general question." By that I take it that you made up that specification, right? Because, as far as I know, no microprocessor has a lower frequency limit.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking about a non-existent specification. OP made it up.

Comment: @DavideAndrea I think old NMOS microprocessors could have a lower frequency limit. E.g. the [NMOS 6500 MICROPROCESSORS](https://web.archive.org/web/20220629085756if_/http://archive.6502.org/datasheets/mos_6500_mpu_nov_1985.pdf) datasheet, which has Nov 1985 in the filename, contains ``Minimum clock frequency = 50 KHz`` in the _Electrical Characteristics_ section.

Comment: @Chester Gillon You are right: I forgot.

Comment: @DavideAndrea Yes. If we look from power dissipation point of view, Clock frequency and power are directly proportional. Therefore, this may impacts it's thermal operation.

Answer (score 2):

If a microprocessor specifies a minimum clock frequency, it means that it uses dynamic logic internally. If you underclock it, you may experience failures because internal nodes don't get refreshed often enough.

But there are usually large margins built into such specifications — in particular, this effect will be worse at elevated temperatures and low supply voltages. If you're operating close to "nominal" conditions, all you can do is try it and see.

Comment: To add a bit to what Dave said.  Those clock frequencies are over the entire operating temperature and supply voltage range.  If you're operating at nominal conditions (supply and temp), you're probable OK at 6MHz.

Comment: @SteveSh: Thanks, I'll add a note about that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer for generic question; it depends on the MCU. If it defines a minimum operating frequency, it is there for some reason.

It might not affect anything if it uses static logic. But in such case there should be no minimum frequency.

If might not work at all if it uses dynamic logic. It needs certain minimum frequecy to work properly.